# What is going on with MySQL integer field matching string?

Tags: mysql

In my inherited database, sometimes binary questions are encoded as ('Yes', 'No'), and sometimes as (1,0). I mistakenly queried against the string 'Yes' on a field which was numerically encoded. My guess is that the string was turned into a '0' by MySQL.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT `children_under_18`
  FROM `households`
 WHERE `children_under_18` = 'Yes'
 GROUP BY `children_under_18`
```

It ended up only matching records where `children_under_18` was 0, the opposite of what I wanted. I know I need to be more careful. I am looking for a definitive answer as to what happened.

Comment: what is the type of `children_under_18`

Comment: Jorge: children_under_18 is an int type. Usually the database designer chose to encode this type of value as enum('Yes', 'No'). I forgot what the encoding was for this field, which is how I obtained undesired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is always converted to 0 when compared to numeric (of course string containing numeric + string is converted numeric. but this is not good practice)

```
mysql> SELECT 'Yes' + 0;
+-----------+
| 'Yes' + 0 |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Yes' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
```

If you want store binary value (Yes/No or True/False) or small value set, `ENUM` is good choice.
It takes small disk space and can use meaningful String.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE enum_test(a ENUM('Yes', 'No'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into enum_test values('Yes'), ('No'), ('Invalid');
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'a' at row 3 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from enum_test where a = 'Yes';
+------+
| a    |
+------+
| Yes  |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from enum_test where a = 'No';
+------+
| a    |
+------+
| No   |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: For a simple boolean, it's arguable that `ENUM` *may* be appropriate (although the truncation of invalid values to the special empty-string value `''` as demonstrated above, in addition to explicit `NULL` values if so permitted, may suggest otherwise).  However, one nevertheless ought to read Chris Komlenic's article [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) before deploying it in a production system.

Comment: @eggyal Great post it is! actually I hadn't used `ENUM` I'm just lazy, but int the future never use it, even if be industrious.